# Windows Excel protected sheet opened in Numbers

Tags: ms-office, password, numbers

**Windows**

I have an Excel file whose all sheets are protected with password, and even the Excel file itself is password protected.  In the Windows version of Excel, I have no issue with this, password protection seems to work as intended.

**Mac**

When I opened the same Excel file from Windows using Numbers on macOS, only the Excel file password works, individual sheet passwords don't work and I can see the formula in Numbers.

Am I doing something wrong in Excel for Windows to protect the workbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numbers is not Excel.

Numbers can only do a subset of things Excel can do with Excel spreadsheets.

If you have done not basic things in Excel (eg protection) you need Excel to undo those things.

This would be true if the original was Numbers and you used Excel on Numbers file.

Each application is different and an export of their specialized file format loses some functionality.

But then again there are things that only Excel can do e.g. Pivot tables.